# How to make Play! Framework 1.4.x preprocessing Java annotations?

Tags: playframework, preprocessor, javac, playframework-1.x, java-annotations

I want to include a Java annotation with source retention in a Play! 1.4.x project, but can't find a way of passing additional arguments to the Play! internal Java compiler in order to make it preprocess the custom annotation.

The annotation is the Adrian Walker's @Multiline preprocessor annotation and following the steps found here: https://github.com/benelog/multiline/wiki/Non-Maven-Java-project-with-Eclipse, I can easily use it in a simple Java console application. However, I can't succeed doing the same in a Play! application.

I guess that I'll have to be able to define the settings used by the internal Java compiler, but I just can't figure how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could suggest is use Play 1 plugin enhancer, but I'm sceptic, since `@Multiline` try to put comment text into java field or variable... such a tricky!

You can try to check directly on the play1 sources, to learn and try to make a plugin/enhancer. I suggest here:
https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPAEnhancer.java
https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPAPlugin.java

And remember to create a `play.plugins` file into `conf` folder of your app.
Good luck.